# node.js \ how to treat to result of sanitize-html

Tags: node.js, html-sanitizing

newbie in Node.js
I try to sanitize htmls in node.js using [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) module- I consider this question more generic from what it may look:

the plugin output an object (I print to console and it states [object]) - how do I know how to work with this object? what are its fields, how to write it to file etc. (I know this may sound basic - should I serialize it? what's the approach to work with object..)

```
var Crawler = require("js-crawler");
var download = require("url-download");
var sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

new Crawler().configure({depth: 1})
  .crawl("http://www.cnn.com", function onSuccess(page) {

    var clean = sanitizeHtml(page);
    console.log(clean);
    fs.writeFile('sanitized.txt', clean, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved! in same location.');
    });

    console.log(util.inspect(clean, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
    var str = JSON.stringify(clean.toString());
    console.log(str);
    /*download(page.url, './download')
    .on('close', function () {
      console.log('One file has been downloaded.');
    });*/
  });
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: attached. tried many things here - how to get content of "clean" variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is not with 'sanitize-html. You are not treating the page variable right. You should use:

```
var clean = sanitizeHtml(page.body);
```